# How to remove the same motif and affect all the other line in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file containing two DNA sequence (with the same number of base) :

```
>seq1
NNNNNAGAATGGGTGANNATTTCCCNN
>seq2
NNAGGGTCCCAATCCNNAACCTTNNNN
```

And I want to remove the position that contain a `N` in one or both sequences. In this example the result would be :

```
>seq1
AGAATGGGTGATTTC
>seq2
GTCCCAATCCACCTT
```

So far I wrote that but it only removes the `N` sequence by sequence :

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' < input | sed 's/N//g' | tr "\t" "\n" > output
```

Can someone has an idea how to do that ?

Biological Context: the FASTA format design how a DNA sequence is written within a text file. It has a first line for the name of the sequence and start with the symbol `>`. Thes second line is for the DNA sequence per se.
In my example I have 2 sequence so I have 4 line

Comment: Thank you, but you are explaining the bio part. What we need to help you is how `NNNNNAGAATGGGTGANNATTTCCCNN` becomes `AGAATGGGTGATTTC`. What is the text pattern that has to be removed? It's not just the `N`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick hack:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    function strip( n ) {
            i = index(body[n], "N")
            while ( i > 0 ) {
                    body[1] = substr(body[1], 0, i-1) substr(body[1], i+1)
                    body[2] = substr(body[2], 0, i-1) substr(body[2], i+1)
                    i = index(body[n], "N")
            }
    }

    /^>/ { 
            N++
            label[N] = $0
            next
    }
    {
            body[N] = $0
    }
    END {
            if ( N != 2 ) {
                    print "Incorrect number of entries" >"/dev/stderr"
                    exit 1
            }
            strip(1)
            strip(2)
            print label[1]
            print body[1]
            print label[2]
            print body[2]
    }
' dna >output
```

File dna is:

```
>seq1
NNNNNAGAATGGGTGANNATTTCCCNN
>seq2
NNAGGGTCCCAATCCNNAACCTTNNNN
```

and file output is:

```
>seq1
AGAATGGGTGATTTC
>seq2
GTCCCAATCCACCTT
```

which I think does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ lines[NR] = $0 }
!/>/ {
    numChars = length($0)
    for ( charPos=1; charPos<=numChars; charPos++)  {
        char = substr($0,charPos,1)
        if ( char == "N" ) {
            badPoss[charPos]
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=NR; lineNr++ ) {
        line = lines[lineNr]
        if ( line ~ />/ ) {
            out = line
        }
        else {
            out = ""
            numChars = length(line)
            for ( charPos=1; charPos<=numChars; charPos++)  {
                if ( !(charPos in badPoss) ) {
                    char = substr(line,charPos,1)
                    out = out char
                }
            }
        }
        print out
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>seq1
AGAATGGGTGATTTC
>seq2
GTCCCAATCCACCTT
```

The above assumes your input file is small enough to fit in memory. If not you can do the same thing by reading the file in 2 passes, the first to create `badPoss[]`, the second to use it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( !/>/ ) {
        numChars = length($0)
        for ( charPos=1; charPos<=numChars; charPos++)  {
            char = substr($0,charPos,1)
            if ( char == "N" ) {
                badPoss[charPos]
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    if ( />/ ) {
        out = $0
    }
    else {
        out = ""
        numChars = length($0)
        for ( charPos=1; charPos<=numChars; charPos++)  {
            if ( !(charPos in badPoss) ) {
                char = substr($0,charPos,1)
                out = out char
            }
        }
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
>seq1
AGAATGGGTGATTTC
>seq2
GTCCCAATCCACCTT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` , you can do as shown with a two pass approach. In the first pass, we build up the masking bits (those where "N" is stored).

```bsh
awk -v OFS= -v _PASS1_=1 '
_PASS1_ {
  if ( /^>/ ) next
  if (n in a)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
     a[i] *= substr($0,i,1) != "N"
  else {
    t=$0
    gsub(/N/,0,t)
    gsub(/[^0]/,1,t)
    gsub(/./,"&"FS,t)
    n=split(t,a)
  }
  next
}
!/^>/{
  t=$0; $0=""
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    $i = a[i] ? substr(t,i,1) : ""
}1
' file _PASS1_=0 file
```

---

Another approach is to transpose the input file and if "N" is seen in any position in the transposed row, that row is marked with a "0", otherwise "1". Then we do one more transpose and obtain the masking bits which then operate on the input rasta file to get the desired o/p.

This uses `GNU sed+BSD rs+awk`.

`rs` is the re-shaper utility to transpose.

```bsh
sed -n '/^>/!s/./& /pg' file |
rs -T | 
sed '/N/s/.*/0/;t;c 1' |
rs -T | 
awk -v OFS= '
NR==1{n=1+split($0,a);next}
!/^>/{
  t=$0
  for (i=$0=""; ++i in a;)
    $i = substr(t, a[i] ? i:n, 1)
}1' - file
```

---

Output:-

```
>seq1
AGAATGGGTGATTTC
>seq2
GTCCCAATCCACCTT
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the two-pass awk approach using `Perl`.

```bsh
perl -spe '
my @A = unpack "(A)*";

s/^[^>].*/@A[@I]/,next if !@ARGV;

unless ( /^>/ ) {
  my $i;
  $M[$i++] =~ s{^1?$}[0+!/N/]e for @A;
}

@I = grep { $M[$_] } 0..$#M if eof;
$_="";
' -- -'"'= file file
```

---

Another method where we pack the dna codons as encoded binary strings in a scalar variable.

```bsh
perl -lMconstant='WIDTH,4' -ne '
  BEGIN {
    my($fmt,@dna,$k) = (sprintf(q(0b%%0%db),WIDTH),qw[N A T C G]);
    %dna = map {
      $_ => oct sprintf $fmt, $k++ } @dna;
    @dna{ values %dna } = keys %dna;
  }

  push(@L,$_),next if /^>/;
  my($bitstr,$offset);

  vec($bitstr, $offset++, WIDTH) =
    $dna{$_} for unpack "(A)*";
  push @L, $bitstr;
  !vec($bitstr,$_,4) && !$h{$_}++
    for 0..--$offset;$a = $offset;
 
  }{
  while (@L) {
    local $_ = shift @L;
    print,next if /^>/;
    my $rec = $_;
    print map { $h{$_} ? () : $dna{vec($rec,$_,WIDTH)} } 0..$a;
  }
' file
```

---

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using `sed` (shown is the `GNU sed`) code in a two-pass way.

```bsh
sed -E '
  /\n/{
    s///;$q;h;d
  }

/^>/{
  N;s/.*\n//
  y/ATCGN/11110/
  G
  s/(.*).$/&\1/
  /^(.*)\n\1$/{s/$/\n/;D;}

  s/^/\n/;ta
  :a;/\n$/D
  s/\n0(.*)\n1/0\n\10\n/;ta
  s/\n.(.*)\n(.)/1\n\1\2\n/;ta
}' file |
sed -E '
  1{h;d;}
  /^>/b
  G;s/^/\n/
  :mask
    s/\n.(.*)\n0/\n\1\n/
    s/\n(.)(.*)\n1/\1\n\2\n/
    s/\n\n$//
  tmask
' - file
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using `Python`, we make use of the fact that python strings are iterable and the zip function does masking by definition.

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys

fasta_in,null = sys.argv[1],""
src,rpl = "ATCGN","11110"

with open(fasta_in) as f:
  m = null
  for _ in f:
    if _.startswith(">"): continue
    l = _.strip()
    if not len(m): m = l
    l = l.translate(l.maketrans(src,rpl))
    m = "".join(["0" if "0" in t else "1" for t in zip(m,l)])

with open(fasta_in) as f:
  for l in f:
    if l.startswith(">"):
      print(l,end=null)
    else:
      print(*[t[0] if t[1] == "1" else null for t in zip(l,m)],sep=null)
' file
```

---

Another method is to employ range objects in Python. Range object is a tuple with a start number(inclusive) and end number(not including).

```bsh
python3 -c 'import re, sys, functools as ft

fasta_in = sys.argv[1]

chomp = lambda x: x.rstrip("\n")
fx = lambda x,y: \
  x[:-1] + [(min(*x[-1],*y),max(*x[-1],*y))] \
  if x[-1][1] >= y[0]-1 else \
  x + [y]

# masking bits as union of ranges
with open(fasta_in) as f:
  L = sorted([t.span()
   for l in map(chomp,f)
   if not l.startswith(">")
   for t in re.finditer(r"N+",l)])
  LoR = ft.reduce(fx,L[1:],L[:1])

with open(fasta_in) as f:
  for l in map(chomp,f):
    if l.startswith(">"): print(l)
    else:
      s = l[:LoR[0][0]]
      s += "".join([
          l[LoR[i-1][1]:LoR[i][0]]
      for i in range(1,len(LoR))])
      s += l[LoR[-1][1]:]
      print(s)
' file
```

---